# Implementing TCP hole punching

Tags: networking, internet

I have theoretical knowledge about TCP hole punching and i want to connect two devices behind two different NATs. What is the easiest way to do so? Is there any softwares for making the task easy?

Comment: A VPN implementation would solve your issue.

Comment: Can you provide some more information or some sources for acquiring the theoretical knowledge for the same?

Comment: OpenVPN and Google are your friends. There many articles on the web regarding the matter.